# Wildcard module declaration not work in typescript 2.x.x, why?

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't this method declaration: `declare module "*!text" {}` is not work?

The goal - to use a file content in a variable:

```
import layout = require("/js/views/layouts/wnd.html!text");
```

or so:

```
import layout from "/js/views/layouts/wnd.html!text";
```

If we do declaration as follows: `declare module "/js/views/layouts/wnd.html!text" {}` -
everything works, but if this method is used `"*!text"` I get an error `cannot find module`. How do I force work this template: `"*!text"`?

The reference [to an example of the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations)

I use systemJS with [plug-in for download text files](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text)

Typescript version - 2.0.6

Answer (score 2):

Typescript doesn't remove this special rule "!text" while transpiling into js file for some reason, (even with moduleResolution set to "node")
[image: transpiled js file]

thus it causes file path resolve failed. (tested with typescript v2.2.1, node.js v6.9.5)

The documents need an update.

Here is a workable version by add custom file extensions:

index.d.ts

```
declare module "*.html" {
    const value: string;
    export default value;
}
```

Extend nodejs module extensions to read *.html into pure text

```
require.extensions['.html'] = function(module, filename) {
    module.exports = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
}
```

And from your example it should works this way:

```
import * as layout from "./js/views/layouts/wnd.html";
console.log(layout);
```

Comment: How are you not running into the TS2352 error as described here?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42829579/typescript-2-wildcard-module

Comment: @RichardCollette I didn't convert it into strong type 'string' for this case. I posted an answer to your question.

Comment: @Val What do you mean here by extend nodejs module extensions? Where would I put that piece of code?

Comment: @Scott Please read this article [How Require Extensions Work](https://gist.github.com/jamestalmage/df922691475cff66c7e6)