# Typescript 2 wildcard module

Tags: angular, module, wildcard, typescript2.2

I am having trouble with importing html templates in my angular 2 app.

In globals.d.ts

```
 declare module "*.html" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

In app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import './app.component.css';
import * as template from './app.component.html';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: <string>template
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log('I am App');
    }
}
```

The app works and the template is loaded but I get this error TS2352: Type 'typeof "*.html"' cannot be converted to type 'string'. Does someone have a workaround?

**I would like to do this instead.**

```
import template from './app.component.html';

@Component({
    template: template
})
...
```

But the transpiled code ends up like this.

```
var app_component_html_1 = __webpack_require__(653);
...
template: app_component_html_1.default
```

app_component_html_1 is the string I need. Why do they add the .default?

Comment: Why are you doing that at all? Why not just `templateUrl: './app.component.html'`?

Comment: Was testing out angular 2 a while back and used templateUrl. But found it hard to use with webpack. Needed extra loaders and steps to make it work. 

I thought  using only template: would be easier. xD

Comment: Just wanted to state that I have the same issue in TS 2.2.   However, my html imports are resolving to a template cache key using ng-cache-loader with webpack.   I have `import * as templateUrl  from './header.template.html';` but then when I go to assign in a directive using `templateUrl: <string>templateUrl` I get the same error as mentioned by the OP.

Comment: I do not know how i fixed the problem, or if i did at all. I did things step by step and the next thing was AOT compiling. From my understanding the `styles: []` is not supported so i had to use `stylesUrl:` If this is your situation too I got a lot of help from these boilerplates. [angular2-aot-webpack](https://github.com/blacksonic/angular2-aot-webpack) and [angular2-course-webpack-starter](https://github.com/mirkonasato/angular2-course-webpack-starter). Hope this can be of any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify `export default content;` to `export = content;` resolved this typescript error.

Before
[image: Not work]

After
[image: Worked]

And the transpiled code should works accordingly (since 'default' is removed).

Comment: Just added a comment to the previous one. Where I explained this no longer was a problem for me. But thanks anyways. Maybe someone else finds this useful.

Comment: I don't know why this works, and it feels like a bug since most of the commentary I have seen in the TS git issues do use default.  However, this is what I'm going with for now.   Thank you.

Comment: I think it's by design - since 'export =' is a valid expression defined in Typescript document.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export--and-import--require